# https call of subdomain is getting htps page of the main domain in apache django deployment

Tags: apache-2.2

when i call **https: //new.sample.com**, i getting page of **https: //sample.com**
but **http: //new.sample.com** is getting the correct page

**sample.com config file**

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>

ServerName sample.com

WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/project/sample.wsgi

</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443>

ServerName www.sample.com 

SSLEngine ON
SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mycerficate.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mykey.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mychain.crt


# Django settings
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/project/wsgi.py

<Directory /path/to/my/project/>
Options -Indexes
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

**new.sample.com config file**

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>

ServerName new.sample.com 
ServerAlias new.sample.com

WSGIPassAuthorization On
# Django settings
WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/project/wsgi_new.py

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It would be useful if you edited your question to include the output of `apachectl -S` or `httpd -t -D DUMP_VHOSTS` to list all configured virtual hosts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, you have only one virtual host configured for requests to Port 443. If no virtual host exists for a specific `Hostname:`, Apache responds to HTTP requests with the first virtual host configured for that particular *IP address / Port number* combination.

You need to create a virtual host configuration for the `new.sample.com` host name listening on Port 443:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443>
    ServerName new.sample.com 
    SSLEngine On
    ...
    WSGIPassAuthorization On
    WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/my/project/wsgi_new.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I've already tried this but i'm getting the same error @Anthony Geoghegan

Comment: can you suggest any other solution @Anthony Geoghegan